# i am a fresher i need help on nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have three tables (questions , options , answers)
in these three table parent model is questions and then child is options and answers
so, i want to delete child data also calling by parent id

**Here is questions models**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import Exam from "../../models/exam.js";

import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";

const Question = sequelize.define("question", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  questiontext: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  questiontexthindi: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  questionImgURL: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  examId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Exam,
      key: "id",
    },
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Question;
```

**options models**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";
import Question from "./question.js";

const Option = sequelize.define("option", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  optiontext: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    // (Sequelize.STRING),
    allowNull: false,
    isLength: [2, 6],
  },

  questionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Question,
      key: "id",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
    },
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Option;
```

**Here is answers models**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";
import Question from "./question.js";
import Option from "./option.js";

const Answer = sequelize.define("answer", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  questionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Question,
      key: "id",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
    },
  },

  optionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: {
      model: Option,
      key: "id",
    },
  },

  correctanswer: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Answer;
```

**Here is my controller**

```
//models
import Question from "../../../models/model-tesportal/option.js";

//helpers
import { validationErrorHandler } from "../../../helpers/validation-error-handler.js";

export const deleteTestSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
  validationErrorHandler(req, next);
  const questionId = req.params.questionId;
  try {
    const result = await Question.destroy({
      where: {
        questionId: questionId,
      },
    });
    if (result[0] === 0) {
      const error = new Error("Question not found");
      error.statusCode = 404;
      return next(error);
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Question Deleted successfully",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

i want to pass questionId in params and then delete data of that particular questionId will be deleted from parent and child tables

Answer (score 0):

**I got the solution from** #geeks for geeks

i have to modify in my models where i wanna access those reference key Id
just look at my models now it works perfectly :

**here is questions model {**parent**}**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import Exam from "../../models/exam.js";

import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";

const Question = sequelize.define("question", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: "id",    **<----- modify here**
 
  },

  questiontext: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  questiontexthindi: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  questionImgURL: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  examId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Exam,
      key: "id",
    },
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Question;
```

**child - options model**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";
import Question from "./question.js";

const Option = sequelize.define("option", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  optiontext: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    // (Sequelize.STRING),
    allowNull: false,
    isLength: [2, 6],
  },

  questionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",    **<----- modify here**
    references: {
      model: Question,
      key: "id",
      FOREIGNKEY: "id",     **<----- modify here**
    },
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Option;
```

**child - answers models**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

import sequelize from "../../utilities/database.js";
import Question from "./question.js";
import Option from "./option.js";

const Answer = sequelize.define("answer", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  questionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",     **<----- modify here**
    references: {
      model: Question,
      key: "id",
      FOREIGNKEY: "id",     **<----- modify here**
    },
  },

  optionId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: {
      model: Option,
      key: "id",
    },
  },

  correctanswer: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },

  isActive: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true,
  },
});
export default Answer;
```

**main code controller**

```
//models
import Question from "../../../models/model-tesportal/question.js";
//helpers
import { validationErrorHandler } from "../../../helpers/validation-error-handler.js";

export const deleteTestSeries = async (req, res, next) => {
  validationErrorHandler(req, next);
  try {
    const result = await Question.destroy({
      where: {
        id: req.params.questionId,
      },
    });

    if (result[0] === 0) {
      const error = new Error("Question not found");
      error.statusCode = 404;
      return next(error);
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Hey Admin Question Deleted successfully",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```